# REGEX strategy to replace line breaks inside group

Tags: regexp-replace

I'm trying to make a replacement in one pass with just one Regular expression but I think this is not possible at all. I'm using RegexBuddy but I'm always getting a catastrophic result and the expression cannot be evaluated.

For this text:

```
3 bla bla! !

4 yep yep! ?

FROM HERE

5 something randdom here!

6 perhaps some HTML there

TO HERE

7 what ever you like over here

8 and that's all folks!enter code here
```

I want to find a REGEX that replaces the line breaks by something else, let's say $$, but only on the section "from here" "to here". So basically the end result would be this:

```
3 bla bla! !

4 yep yep! ?

FROM HERE$$
$$
5 something randdom here!$$
$$
6 perhaps some HTML there$$
$$
TO HERE

7 what ever you like over here

8 and that's all folks!
```

I have this expression

```
((FROM HERE))((.*)(\n))+(TO HERE)
```

But I'm stuck so far trying to replace just the \n group by something else. I have done similar things in the past so I would say this should be possible in one go.

If this is not possible in regex I would simply create a C# console app to take first that text to a string and then replace each \n by $$, then put it back. That shouldn't be that difficult.

Comment: Did the answer work out?

Comment: @Thefourthbird it did thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using .NET, one option could be

```
(?s)(?<=^FROM HERE\b.*?)\r?\n\r?\n(?=.*?^TO HERE\b)
```

- `(?s)` Inline modifier, dot matches a newline
- `(?<=^FROM HERE\b.*?)` Assert `FROM HERE` at the left at the start of the line
- `\r?\n\r?\n` Match 2 newlines
- `(?=.*?^TO HERE\b)` Assert `TO HERE` at the right at the start of the line

In the replacement use (with double escapes `$$`)

```
\n$$$$\n
```

See a [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fs%29%28%3f%3c%3d%5eFROM+HERE%5cb.*%3f%29%5cr%3f%5cn%5cr%3f%5cn%28%3f%3d.*%3f%5eTO+HERE%5cb%29&i=3+bla+bla!+!%0d%0a%0d%0a4+yep+yep!+%3f%0d%0a%0d%0aFROM+HERE%0d%0a%0d%0a5+something+randdom+here!%0d%0a%0d%0a6+perhaps+some+HTML+there%0d%0a%0d%0aTO+HERE%0d%0a%0d%0a7+what+ever+you+like+over+here%0d%0a%0d%0a8+and+that%27s+all+folks!enter+code+here&r=%5cn%24%24%24%24%5cn&o=m) and a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/bFNKkJ).

Comment: This is a perfect start point, I will develop this futher. Thank you very much!